# Javascript compare 2 dates and result must be setTimeout() Method in ms

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare to 2 dates by hour/minutes/seconds, in order to make a script to resume a script when closed. If current `time` is pass `closed time + interval ( currently set at 30 minutes)` should execute and run the script normally, if not wait till `difference` timeouts to execute.

Current hour/minutes/seconds is not a must but the result should be in ms interval

Example:

```
interval = (30 * 60 * 1000)
close time = 15:10:53
current time = 15:15:29
close time + interval = 15:40:53

first time I check if `current time` <= `close time + interval`
then calculate `difference` 
`difference` = (close time + interval = 15:40:53) - (current time = 15:15:29)

Result should be setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time difference);
```

The only way I'm thinking of doing this is calculate each difference from Hour,Minutes,Seconds and then finding out the ms for setTimeout

I tried but results were weird, not something that would count as smaller than 30min

```
var ONE_S = 1000 ;  
var timeDiff = Math.abs(closeTime - currentTime); 
var diffS = Math.round(timeDiff/ONE_S)
```

Comment: Your top code looks like pseudocode. The bottom looks like real code but is using variables not even defined in your pseudocode. You should show more of what you have tried in real code!

Comment: you sure want to use the timestamp for such kind of situations. currentTime.getTimetamp() - closeTime.getTimestamp() = timeDiff

Comment: The bottom code is just a test that did not work, the only real variables that are needed are closeTime , currentTime, closeTime+Interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date` objects and compare timestamps like so:

```
var interval = 30 * 60 * 1000;
var closeTime = new Date('Wed Nov 26 2015 10:17:44 GMT-0400 (AST)');
var currentTime = new Date;
var difference = (closeTime - currentTime) + interval;

if(difference < 0) {
  console.log('time has expired');
}else{
  setTimeout(someFunction, difference);
}
```

`closeTime - currentTime` gets the time between timestamps in ms, which will be negative if it's past closing time. We offset closing time by 30 minutes (by adding `interval`). Then we just have to check if `difference < 0` to know if time has expired, and if not we can wait `difference` milliseconds to trigger `someFunction`

Comment: Yet again, the difference is a weird number 35684914443

Comment: @Alex_TNT can you paste what you're using for `closeTime`? In my example above my difference is 87334882 which makes perfect sense because it's approximately 86400000 which is 1 day.

Comment: Damn, Seems like that was the problem : `var closeTime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
   + ("0" + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-"
   + ("0" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)  + " "

   + ("0" + currentdate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":"
   + ("0" + currentdate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":"
   + ("0" + currentdate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);` instead of just inserting Date()

Comment: you should not convert your dates to a string and then compare them -- you can compare two dates by subtracting one from the other, and the result will be in ms. It's much easier.